# converting date from Nvarchar to smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert date column which is formatted like: **Dec/21/2017 06:42:57 AM**  to show **2017/Dec/21 06:42 AM** but keep getting:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Here is the code I am using:

```
DECLARE 

@FI NVARCHAR(10) =''
,@SLA_MONTH INT = 9 


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SLA_ALL') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SLA_ALL
SELECT [Main FI],Batchno,[Legal Entity Name],I.[Goldtier ID]
, I.[Date and Time notification recieved from FI to upload entities to TR]

,MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(P.[Create Timestamp],8,4)+'/'
+SUBSTRING(P.[Create Timestamp],1,3)+'/'
+SUBSTRING(P.[Create Timestamp],5,2)+' '
+SUBSTRING(P.[Create Timestamp],13,5) AS smalldatetime))

[Keys Generated]
,MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME,C.Timestamp)) 'Consent recevied'
,MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME,S.Timestamp)) 'Documents Requested (Timestamp for when the OI task was "Ready to Send")' 
,MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME,O.[Start Date])) 'Documents Requested (Timestamp for when the OI task was communicated to the FI)' 
,COALESCE(MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME,A.[Timestamp])),NULL) 'Attestation sent to the FI'
,'' 'PR sent to the FI' 
,'PRIMARY FI: '+PR.[FI Name] +' AND NON-PRIAMARY FI:'+PR.[Non Primary FI] [PRC RAISED]
,sa.Status
INTO #SLA_ALL


FROM LANDING.Import_Entity I
LEFT JOIN [Promotional Keys] P ON I.[Goldtier ID] = P.[End Client ID]
LEFT JOIN SLA_ReadyToSend S ON I.[Goldtier ID] = S.[Entity ID] and  S.[Financial Institution ID] =CASE WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'RM' THEN '863772678'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'SCB' THEN 836553196
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'STD' THEN 710689297
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'ETH' THEN 309300771
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'AB' THEN    995668333
                                                                            END 
LEFT JOIN attestation_Sent_To_FI A ON I.[Goldtier ID] = A.[Entity ID] and CASE WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'RM' THEN 863772678
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'SCB' THEN 836553196
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'STD' THEN 710689297
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'ETH' THEN 309300771
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'AB' THEN    995668333
                                                                            END = A.[FI ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN DAILY_OUTSTANDING_STATS O ON I.[Goldtier ID] = O.[End Client Org ID Number] and CASE WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'RM' THEN '863772678'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'SCB' THEN '836553196'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'STD' THEN '710689297'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'ETH' THEN '309300771'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'AB' THEN    '995668333'
                                                                            END = O.[FI ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN SA_MASTER_BASE SA ON I.[Goldtier ID] = SA.[GoldTier ID] AND SA.Status <> 'CLOSED' AND CASE WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'RM' THEN '863772678'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'SCB' THEN '836553196'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'STD' THEN '710689297'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'ETH' THEN '309300771'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'AB' THEN    '995668333'
                                                                            END = SA.[FI ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONSENT_RECEIVED C ON I.[Goldtier ID] = C.[Entity ID] AND C.[Financial Institution ID] = CASE WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'RM' THEN '863772678'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'SCB' THEN '836553196'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'STD' THEN '710689297'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'ETH' THEN '309300771'
                                                                        WHEN I.[Main FI] = 'AB' THEN    '995668333'
                                                                        END
LEFT JOIN PRC PR ON I.[Goldtier ID] = PR.[GoldTier ID]
WHERE 1=1 
AND @SLA_MONTH = MONTH(I.[Date and Time notification recieved from FI to upload entities to TR])

GROUP BY[Main FI],Batchno,[Legal Entity Name],I.[Goldtier ID],SA.Status,[Date and Time notification recieved from FI to upload entities to TR],PR.[FI Name],PR.[Non Primary FI]

GO
```

I have also checked my smalldatetime on my laptop, it is set as yyyy/mm/dd.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Two reasons you won't get your desired result - `smalldatetime` cannot count seconds, and a `smalldatetime` doesn't **have** a format. It's effectively 2 16-bit ints, one storing "days since 01/01/1900" and the other storing "minutes since midnight". Don't confuse what you see when you ask to be shown it (and so it's necessarily converted into a *string*) with what the data type actually is.

Comment: I have tried to replace the smalldatetime with nvarchar and i get the same result?

Comment: Could you write the declaration of fields of table `LANDING.Import_Entity`?

Answer (score 0):

To save cast the date string to smalldatetime, I think you can convert to datetime first and then cast to smalldatetime.

```
declare @CreateTimestamp nvarchar(23)
set @CreateTimestamp = 'Dec/21/2017 06:42:57 AM'

--SELECT convert(datetime, 'Dec 21 2017 06:42AM', 100)
select
CAST(
    convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(@CreateTimestamp,1,3)
    +' '+SUBSTRING(@CreateTimestamp,5,2)
    +' '+SUBSTRING(@CreateTimestamp,8,4)
    +' '+SUBSTRING(@CreateTimestamp,13,5)
    +SUBSTRING(@CreateTimestamp,22,2), 100)
AS smalldatetime)
```

Here is the **convert** function details:
http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh213316(v=sql.110))?

```
select parse('Dec/21/2017 06:42:57 AM' as smalldatetime)
```

To then convert back from a datetime to a string, use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
declare @sdt smalldatetime

set @sdt = parse('Dec/21/2017 06:42:57 AM' as smalldatetime)
select @sdt [SmallDateTime]
, format(@sdt, 'yyyy/MMM/dd hh:mm tt') [Formatted]
```

[See Runnable Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=58afde0e7a7a9b720c39a360de64da23)